# Libgdx game out of memory and crashes

Tags: android, memory-management, libgdx, out-of-memory

Hey i made a little game of fishes that are moving on the screen and the user needs to hit them and kill them, after 2-3 minutes the app just get terminated completely and i can't figure out why, i am just creating the objects once and moving them on the screen..

the message i am getting is

```
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4771(2029KB) AllocSpace objects, 230(4MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/16MB, paused 3.054ms total 173.279ms
```

here is some of the code:
the creation of the image array:

```
fishes = new Image[30];
    directionX = new int[30];
    directionY = new int[30];
    speed = new int[30];
    dead = new boolean[30];
    deadTimer = new int[30];


    Random random = new Random();
   Drawable drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("idag.png")));

    for(int i =0;i<fishes.length;i++)
    {
        int xlocation = random.nextInt(2);
        int ylocation = random.nextInt(2);
        dead[i] = false;
        deadTimer[i] = 0;

        fishes[i] = new Image(drawable);
        fishes[i].setWidth(character.getWidth()/3);
        fishes[i].setHeight(character.getWidth()/3);
        GenerateLocation(i);

        stage.addActor(fishes[i]);
    }
```

and here is the generating of every fish position when it is dead

```
 public void GenerateLocation(int i) {
     random = new Random();

        int xlocation = random.nextInt(2);
        int ylocation = random.nextInt(2);
        if (xlocation == 0) {
            fishes[i].setX(-random.nextInt(8000));
            directionX[i] = 1;

        } else {
            fishes[i].setX(width + random.nextInt(8000));
            directionX[i] = -1;
        }

        if (ylocation == 0) {
            fishes[i].setY(random.nextInt((int) (height/2)));
            directionY[i] = 1;
        } else {


            fishes[i].setY(height-random.nextInt((int) (height/2)));
            directionY[i] = -1;
        }

        if (directionX[i] == 1 && directionY[i] == 1) {
            drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("idag-45.png")));
            fishes[i].setDrawable(drawable);
            //fishes[i].setRotation(-45);

        } else if (directionX[i] == 1 && directionY[i] == -1) {
            drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("idag-135.png")));
            fishes[i].setDrawable(drawable);
        } else if (directionX[i] == -1 && directionY[i] == 1) {
            drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("idag45.png")));
            fishes[i].setDrawable(drawable);
        } else if (directionX[i] == -1 && directionY[i] == -1) {
            drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("idag135.png")));
            fishes[i].setDrawable(drawable);
        }
        speed[i] = random.nextInt(levelSpeed) + 1;

}
```

Can anyone help me? i really don't know what else can i do the make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of `new Texture` calls there so you are generating a lot of Objects. Anything in LibGDX that implements Disposable must be disposed of with a call to `dispose()` before you lose your reference to it. This is because a Disposable holds data in native memory, so the GC won't clean it up.

Also, it is a waste of time to load the same images over and over instead of reusing the same Texture instance. Every one of your fish has another copy of the same images loaded into memory for itself.

Comment: Ok, about the new Texture i fixed it, I created 4 drawables in the constructor and whenever i want to change the image i am referencing to them, the game is still crashing, i even tried to dispose the whole stage when i lose and is still crashes, i really don't get why.

Comment: I don't either because I can't see your code or your stack trace. ;)